# Translating Virtual and Physical Address

Tags: memory, memory-address

So I really don't get this. Can anyone explain how to do these problems?

Suppose we have a 32-bit CPU with a paging-based memory system. The size of a page is 4KB(2^12). Now the CPU generates a virtual addres 0x0000AAA

1.) What is the virtual page number of this virtual address? What is the page offset?

2.) Using the page table below, translte the above virtual address into physical address - in hex representation. The page table shows the first 5 entries.

0 - 0xAAAAA
1 - 0xBBBBB
2 - 0xCCCCC
3 - 0xDDDDD
4 - 0xEEEEE

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried?

Comment: It is not homework it is exam review. I know the answer I just don't really understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size of a page is 4KB (= 4096 bytes), that means all addresses from 0 up to, and including 4095 (0x00000fff) are in the first page.

0x0000aaa is less than 0x00000fff, so this is still in the first page (page #0).

To obtain the physical address corresponding with virtual address 0x00000aaa, lookup the prefix for page #0, which is 0xAAAAA.

Comment: Thank you, for the clear explanation. So just to make sure let say the address given would have been 0x00001AAA. That would mean it would be in the second page? So I would go to the table and find the second page and in this example it is 0xBBBBB?

Comment: Correct. In your second example, the physical address would end up being 0xBBBBBAAA.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is given that page size is 4 KB, it means a page has 4K addresses. Hence we need 12 bits to reach every address in a page.
Hence, page offset = 12 bits .

Since, the system is 32 bit, hence 20 bits will be used as page number.

Since page size is equal to frame size, therefore the frame offset = 12 bits.
Now, use the page table to use get the physical address.